# Netbeans dist jar file giving NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, executable-jar, classnotfoundexception

Yes I have a project that I'm working on in NetBeans 7.1 and I come to the point where I want to use the jar file on a different computer but when I try to run it it gives a NoClassDefFoundError. But when I run it on my computer it works fine. I've extracted the .jar file all the classes seem to be there. I've checked to see if netbeans thinks my project is the main project and that it has a main class which I also confirmed in the MANIFEST.MF file. My program does have swing components if that affects anything.

Edit
Also there are no other folders in my dist folder like any lib or picture folders
I have also clean and rebuilt about a hundred times
/Edit

Here is the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ClubControl.jar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I have searched through countless articles on this subject and still I don't think I have found the problem. Hopefully I didn't miss it and someone responds with a link to another question.

If any other info is needed just ask.

Edit

here is the MF file

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.7.0_01-b08 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: GUI.MainWindow
```

Comment: All of my class files are in two folders/packages and when I extract the .jar file I confirmed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception stacktrace it would seem that a class is misnamed somewhere in your code:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ClubControl.jar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
```

It appears to be trying to load up a class named `ClubControl.jar` - there should be no extension on the name, and definitely not a *.jar* one.

Comment: No all my java files have a package.

Comment: I misread your stacktrace - lack of sleep! While going over it again I did notice that the class its trying to load has an odd name (.jar extension?). You might want to check that.

Comment: I don't know why it would be looking for that file. This error was given from a mac, when run on a pc the error given is that the program cannot find the GUI.MainWindow class. I added the MF file above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include other dependencies of the .jar. Like /lib folder or sometimes if you have images on the project you have to include those as well and make sure that the .jar can locate those dependencies. And try to Clean and Build the Netbeans project.

Comment: I don't have any lib folders and I don't think there are any dependencies. I have also ran Clean and Build plenty of times.